# mover carpeta desde el home

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

En mi $home tengo la carpeta: BLACKICEcoder y quiero moverla hasta htdocs pero me sale este error.
mv: cannot move 'BLACKICEcoder' ....No such file or directory
La ruta a donde lo quiero mover es esta:
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/apache2/default-site/htdocs

Y este es el comando que utilizo

```
cd
mv $home/BLACKICEcoder /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/apache2/default-site/htdocs
```

Comment: si haces `ls -l $home/BLACKICEcoder`, ¿te la encuentra?

Comment: Ya le puse este comando ~ $ ls -l $home/BLACKICEcoder
ls: cannot access '/BLACKICEcoder': No such file or directory y me salio ese error

Answer (score 0):

Listo, ya he resueltoel problema con este comando
primero investigo en cual carpeta me encuentro con Pwd y luego muevo el archivo a donde lo quiero enviar con mv

pwd
/data/home/blackicecoder
mv /data/home/blackicecoder/ (ruta de la carpeta a donde se quiere mover)